# Positioning difficulties

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position two images and running into difficulties. I want the 'Welcome!' speech bubble to be just to the left of the logo.

Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```css
html {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

img {
 width: 100px;
 height: 150px;
}

#logo {
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
}

#welcome {
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
}

#popUp {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Placehold</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='logo'>
   <img src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah72/michaelbarley1/logo_zpsopheofmw.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div id='welcome'>
   <img id='popUp' src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah72/michaelbarley1/welcome_zps3xaw6gge.png" alt="welcome">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy fix would be to switch the ordering of the HTML so that the welcome bubble div is before the logo div. All you will have to do then is float each div to the left.

```css
html {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

img {
 width: 100px;
 height: 150px;
}

#logo {
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
    float:left;
}

#welcome {
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
    float:left;
}

#popUp {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Placehold</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='welcome'>
   <img id='popUp' src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah72/michaelbarley1/welcome_zps3xaw6gge.png" alt="welcome">
  </div>
  <div id='logo'>
   <img src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah72/michaelbarley1/logo_zpsopheofmw.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```